# Difference between grant command using or not any

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-grant

i'm doubt about the command to grant permissions to users in a Oracle database.

Look, i can grant permission with or without the command ANY,,,
Example, i can use the follows command to grant crate mviews:

```
GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO <USER>;
```

OR

```
GRANT CREATE ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW TO <USER>;
```

so, 
what's the difference between both?! Using **ANY** or not...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is:

```
GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO <USER>;
```

Let you create materialized views in your schema.

```
GRANT CREATE ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW TO <USER>;
```

Let you create materialized views in all schemas.

You can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm) for more information.